# Dynamic conditional logic function

Tags: logic

I need to write a function that can take an if statement at runtime (eg. user input, or from a data file). Ideally it should be able to solve an expression no less complex than:

```
a && ( b || !c || ( d && e ) )
```

I imagine what I need is a recursive function (one that calls itself). Of course, the function needs to return *true* or *false*.

Because of the complexity of the example above, the function would need to not only loop through the individual conditions, but understand the operators, know the order in which to evaluate them and preferably prioritise them for speed (eg. in the example, if *a* is *false* there is no need to evaluate the rest of the statement).

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: What language are you using? Some include libraries that can do that for you in one line of code.

Comment: I'm using PHP, but I don't want to use something like JavaScript's *eval* method, for security reasons, and I'd like to be able to customise the syntax too.

Comment: If you want a PHP solution you should add that tag to your question (edit link below the question).

Comment: I didn't see the question as language-specific as it could apply to pretty much any programming language. I want the solution to be more of a technique or pattern than something that only applies to PHP developers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution would be using shunting yard algorithm to convert the expression to RPN, and then evaluate it as RPN (because RPN is much easier to evaluate than infix). The first part, conversion to RPN (in pseudocode):

```
while (tokens left) {
  t = read_token();
  if (t is number) {
    output(t);
  } else if (t is unary operator) {
    push(t);
  } else if (t is binary operator) {
    r = pop();
    if (r is operator and precedence(t)<=precedence(r)) {
       output(r);
    } else {
       push(r);
    }
    push(t);
  } else if (t is left parenthesis) {
    push(t);
  } else if (r is right parenthesis) {
    while ((r = pop()) is not left parenthesis) {
        output(r);
        if (stack is empty) {
          mismatched parenthesis!
        }
    }
    if (top() is unary operator) {
        output(pop());
    }
  }
}
while (stack is not empty) {
  if (top() is parenthesis) {
     mismatched parenthesis!
  }
  output(pop());
}
```

- `read_token` reads a token from input queue
- `output` inserts a value into output queue
- `push` pushes a value into the stack (you only need one)
- `pop` pops a value out of a stack
- `top` peeks the value at the top of the stack without popping

The RPN evaluation is simpler:

```
while (tokens left) {
  t = read_token();
  if (t is number) {
    push(t);
  } else if (t is unary operator) {
    push(eval(t, pop()));
  } else if (t is binary operator) {
    val1 = pop();
    val2 = pop();
    push(eval(t, val1, val2));
  }
}
result = pop();
```

- `read_token()` reads values from the RPN queue generated in previous step
- `eval(t, val)` evaluates unary operator `t` with operand `val`
- `eval(t, val1, val2)` evaluates binary operator `t` with operands `val1` and `val2`
- `result` is the final value of the expression

This simplified algorithm should work if all your operators are left-associative and no functions are used. Note that no recursion is necessary, because we use our own stack implementation.
For examples and more information, see [Rosetta Code on Shunting-yard](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Parsing/Shunting-yard_algorithm) and [Rosetta Code on RPN](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Parsing/RPN_calculator_algorithm)

Comment: Thank you for your very informative answer. I shall read up on RPN and give it a go.

Comment: If I convert my example to RPN, should I get `a b c || d e && ! || &&`?

Comment: Or should it be `a b c ! d e && || &&`?

Comment: a b c ! d e && || && sounds better: c ! translates to !c, d e && translates to d && e etc

Comment: Or even `a b c ! d e && || || &&`?

Comment: Let's see... The innermost d e && is clear: d && e. As is c !: !c. The || just right to them joins them to !c || (d && e). The other || brings b || !c || (d && e), and the last && makes it a && (b || !c || (d && e)). Sounds right.

Comment: I think I've got it now, thanks a lot Ilmo Euro. I believe there is an error in your Shunting Yard code though: when t is a binary operator, it must always be pushed to the stack, not just when r is not output.